# What the forklift is this gold piece on my push/pull connector?

Tags: connector, push-pull, screw-terminal

I got a pseudo-lemo connector that seems to go together in the order the parts are laid down on the plastic baggy. The solder cup goes into the sliding part, and the rubber goes on the end to give some support to the wire.

Only problem is the gold piece doesn't fit on anything. What is it, where does it go? Also, what is the tiny hole next to V8 used for?

[image][image]

Comment: Where does the forklift play in?

Comment: @calcium3000 I didn't want to use any explicit language, but also wanted to vent my frustration in trying to figure out where the gold piece goes. Forklift seemed like a good compromise.

Comment: Looks like a crimp fitting of some sort... IMHO

Comment: What's the part number?  The datasheet should shed some light.  It might be used to clamp the shield to the backshell.

Comment: Looks like a [LF Series](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=LF&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D51100_en) Page 10 & 11 look like they show the assembly instructions for the Strain Relief Collar (the gold part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a cable grip used for internal strain relief.

After the terminations have been made the clip is placed around the outer insulation, crimped - biting the insulation with the teeth - and the cable strain relief is then tightened. It prevents the cable being yanked out of the connector.

[image]

*Figure 1. The set screw is used to grip the clamp.*

The assembly diagram shows the connector during assembly. Once the P shell unit is soldered on the plug body and cord bushing are slid down over the clamp and P shell. The set screw (1) is then tightened against the clamp (2) to grip the outer insulation and eliminate stress on the conductors and solder connections.

Comment: Added in an image from the datasheet to my post. It was a Hirose HR10 type. The hole was for a placeholder screw.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked with this connector before. It seemed straightforawrd enough at the time ...

[image: parts]

The gold part gets crimped onto the outer jacket of your cable, such that it will end up inside the main body of the connector aligned with the band marked "V8", where the setscrew goes.

Then, you tighten the setscrew so that its point goes into either of the two dimples in the gold band.

This provides a secure strain relief, regardless of the actual diameter of your cable.